# Linker error structure header in C

Tags: linker, structure, global

I have structure declaration in a header
globalStruct.h

```
#ifndef _GLOBALSTRUCT_H
#define _GLOBALSTRUCT_H
typedef struct 
    {
        
        Int32   frameID;
        Int32   slotIndx;
        Int32   symNumber;

    }   recControlList;     
        recControlList  *recControlListPtr;

#endif
```

fun.h is

## include "globalStruct.h"

void fun( recControlList *recControlListPtr);

Inside File1.c I do the following

```
#include "globalStruct.h"
#include "fun.h"

recControlList  temp;
recControlListPtr=&temp;

fun( recControlListPtr); //Function prototype is declared in some fun.h file.
```

fun.c looks like

```
#include "globalStruct.h"
```

void  fun( recControlList *recControlListPtr)

I get linker error: _recControlListPtr defined multiple times.
one in File1.c and other fun.c

I don't understand what is wrong here? globalStruct needs extern?

Thanks

Comment: I've formatted your code pastes. Can you also post fun.h ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include guards won't help you here. They will stop a single compilation unit from getting two copies of the data if it includes the header file twice but you have two *totally separate* compilation units here. The compiler will put a `recControlListPtr` in *both* of the object files.

Then, when you link those object files together, the linker will complain because there are two instances of that symbol.

What you need to do is ensure that only one instance exists. In your header file, replace:

```
recControlList  *recControlListPtr;
```

with:

```
extern recControlList  *recControlListPtr;
```

Then, in *one* of your C files, put:

```
recControlList  *recControlListPtr;
```

---

Bottom line: try to avoid defining anything in header files. Declaring things (stating *that* they exist, like prototypes, externs, typedefs, structs and so on) is okay, defining (allocating space for variables, giving the bodies of functions ans so on) is generally not.

Comment: Hi Paxdiablo!  Thanks it has solved the prob. I dont know if this error is related, but I had read somewhere that structures are not "Extern". Now I put extern as u suggested and things are fine.. Any inputs on extern for structures ? or ive misread..

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of the context but extern would apply to the _variable_ of type structure. Not the structure definition itself. A quick search of the web turns up a lot of things where people tried to extern a variable of a specifiic structure type, but where the type definition wasn't in effect. That's the only thing I can think of. If you can point me to someplace specific, I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you include a header file more than once throughout your program you have to either:

a) be more careful with the declarations you have in the header

OR

b) put include guards to make sure that the header doesn't get included twice, read up on include guards IFNDEF and IFDEF for more info.

PM

Comment: Hi correction: I have conditional #define guard.( forgot to put in the snippet)  I am still having this error